# Refer to resource key from within resource-file

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

I once had a WinForms application in which I used a static class for simple string resources. In this class I had constant strings I could acces. One of those strings consisted of the value of another constant, plus its own value. Something like this:

```
private const string Path = @"C:\SomeFolder\";
public const string FileOne = Path + "FileOne.txt";
public const string FileTwo = Path + "FileTwo.txt";
```

Now I have a WPF application and I am using a ResourceDictionary, which I merged to Application scope. Everything works fine, but I want something similar like the C# code above. This is what I already have:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <System:String x:Key="Path">C:\SomeFolder\</System:String>
    <System:String x:Key="FileOne">FileOne.txt</System:String>
    <System:String x:Key="FileTwo">FileTwo.txt</System:String>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Now I need something (some kind of reference to 'Path') that is automatically added to the two file-strings, it doesn't need to be private like in the C# code. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use it i XAML, here are two ideas for you:

**Idea 1: one `Binding`**

In your resources, only add the `Path`:

```
<System:String x:Key="Path">C:\SomeFolder\</System:String>
```

And, somewhere in your XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text='{Binding Source={StaticResource Path}, StringFormat={}{0}FileOne.txt}' />
```

This will display Path+"FileOne.txt"

(note: you can write whatever you want instead of FileOne.txt )

You can have custom stuff using this way.

**Idea 2: One `MultiBinding`**

More convenient for what you are trying to do imho: you keep those three `Resources` you defined.

If you want to call them somewhere so that Path + fileOne will be displayed, just use that (example with a `TextBlock` )

```
    <TextBlock >
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}{1}">
                <Binding Source="{StaticResource Path}" />
                <Binding Source="{StaticResource FileOne}" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
```

That's all you need!

Alternatively if you don't use those `String`s in your UI, you can still use a static class. But using the XAML way is cleaner imho (all UI-related stuff should stay in XAML anyway)

Answer (score 1):

You can still use a static class with resources:

```
namespace WpfStaticResources
{
    class MyResources {
        private const string Path = @"C:\SomeFolder\";
        public const string FileOne = Path + "FileOne.txt";
        public const string FileTwo = Path + "FileTwo.txt";
    }
}
```

and then from your XAML reference that as:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfStaticResources.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:WpfStaticResources="clr-namespace:WpfStaticResources" 
    Title="{x:Static WpfStaticResources:MyResources.FileOne}" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Personally I'd prefer to not use a static class, but instead create a domain object, set it as your DataContext and then bind to properties on it instead.

Comment: In my WPF application I started out with a static class like you suggested. But I wanted to use the ResourceDictionary as this is what it's meant for. But thanks for thinking along! ;)